# How can I attach a set of five panniers?

Tags: panniers

My ex's mother gave me her old set of five panniers. When researching it seems that they normally come in sets of two and, as I understand, they normally attached to a rack over the rear tire.

Having five, I'm not sure where all of these go without getting in the way of the rest of my bike. There just doesn't seem to be an arrangement where they would all fit.

[image]
[image]

- Pictured at top: The top two have rectangular backing plates, so these seem like standard rear tire mounted panniers.
- Pictured at bottom (the one with the reflector): It seems like a front or back pannier? No hooks, only bungies.
- Pictured in middle (two oddly shaped ones): The very large, backing plate has five sides shaped like a sideways baseball diamond. They have hooks as well.
  The brand seems to be REI PeakValue, but my searching turned up little on this brand.

How would all of these mount to a bike?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The top pair should attach to a rack on the front fork legs. The middle pair is for the rear, and the slope on the backing plate is to provide heel clearance. The fifth bag looks like it should mount to the front of the handlebars.

Comment: Never would have guessed... Thanks. I thought the slope for the middle pair might have gone parallel to the down tube and then mount to the top tube. This makes much more sense.

Comment: @Coburn Note that handlebar bags negatively influence handling much more than the other types. Try to keep the load light in that bag.

Comment: There is a photo on the [Wikipedia panniers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pannier) entry illustrating them mounted as you describe.

Comment: The white reflector on the handlebar bag is a tell about its intended location.

Comment: There's nothing to stop you strapping the front one on top of your rear rack, other than weight distribution.   Some bikes just don't do well with a handlebar bag.